# JQuery splice array deleting wrong

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, cordova

I'm making a hybrid app with cordova and I have two problems

1. When I double tap an item in my list it removes the correct item, however when I close and re-open the app it has removed the last one in the list instead, so basically, it removes the one I double tap on screen but in the array it always removes the last item in the list.
2. I can't remove a item i just added from the list, I need to close and re-open the app to remove it.

The problems occur in the bottom function

Here's my javascript file(JQuery):

```
    var taskListArray = new Array();

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var addInput = $("#addInput");
        var taskList = $("#taskList");

        if(window.localStorage)
        {
            taskListArray = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("taskList"))
        }
        else
        {
            window.plugins.toast.showLongCenter("LocalStorage not found, saving unavailable!");
        }

        if(taskListArray != null)
        {
            for(i = 0; i < taskListArray.length; i++)
            {
                var task = "<li>" + taskListArray[i].task + "</li>";
                taskList.append(task);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            taskListArray = new Array();
        }

        $("#addButton").on("click", function()
        {
            if($("#addInput").val() != 0)
            {
                var task = "<li>" + addInput.val() + "</li>";
                taskList.append(task);
                taskListArray.push({task:addInput.val()});

                if(window.localStorage)
                {
                    window.localStorage.setItem("taskList", JSON.stringify(taskListArray));
                }

                addInput.val("");
                window.plugins.toast.showShortCenter("Task added!");
            }
        });

        $("li").dblclick(function()
        {
            //Removes last task instead of the task I double tapped on
            //and I can't remove newly added tasks
            taskListArray.splice($.inArray($(this), taskListArray), 1);

            $(this).remove();
            window.plugins.toast.showShortCenter("Task removed!");

            if(window.localStorage)
            {
                window.localStorage.setItem("taskList", JSON.stringify(taskListArray));
            }
        });
    });
```

Edit: Still no answer to question #2? I would really appreciate answers to both questions or one at least, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `$.inArray` needs two arguments, but you are only passing one. With only one parameter the function returns -1 and the `splice` function removes the last element when the argument is -1. It should be something like this `taskListArray.splice($.inArray($(this), taskListArray), 1);`. [JQuery inArray Doc](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Comment: Oh you are wrapping the innerHtml in an object then try a filter `var value = $(this).html(); taskListArray = taskListArray.filter(ele => ele.task !== value);` instead. Or iterate manually over the items.

Comment: I have no idea what that second line does so i just copied what you wrote and tried it but it didn't work anyway, did I do something wrong? All I did was replace the "splice" line with the two lines you wrote.

Comment: Here a little fiddle with the core content (I think)  without the storage things. You must also add new `dblClick` function for the new created `<li>` the `$("li").dblclick` is only adding the callback function to the `<li>` currently in the DOM. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zc7vmgjr/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please replace your code
taskListArray.splice($.inArray($(this)), 1);
with
taskListArray.splice($.inArray($(this),taskListArray), 1);
and try.

In the jQuery documentation its stated that you need to provide the array in which u need to search.

jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ] )